# After resetting the mediaplayer , the play button is not working

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, reset, playback

I m making an app for playing audio in which I have made play, pause and reset button.All button are working when the app starts, if I play the audio and reset it, after pressing the reset button , if I again press the play button, the audio does not play.

```
package com.example.android.mediaplayer;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mmediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         mmediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);

        Button b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing sound",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        mmediaPlayer.start();
                        mmediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Song is done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
        Button b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_button);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mmediaPlayer.pause();
            }
        });
        Button b3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.reset_button);
        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mmediaPlayer.reset();
            }
        });

    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you call mediaPlayer.reset(), you then must also call the prepare method.

You can also to do this instead:
mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
mediaPlayer.pause();

Then you can call play again to start music from 0.